# Callback from 3 child components renders the parent application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon, the problem I have is that I have a Hook that saves the value that I get from 2 levels of child components within the parent component.
hook parent > 1 child >  child | child | child (these 3 on the same level) . I am using the useCallback function passing an object as a parameter and doing set in the hook but the parent application renders as many times as the value is updated.

I add a graph to explain it better.

[image]

I need that every time the data is updated, the parent application is not rendered since I have the component inside a form and if I add data to the fields and later use the hook, the data disappears.

Comment: If you are using useState from the parent component it will re-render the parent component.  See https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide

Comment: Do you require the child component to render every time the value is updated? If not then just use a regular variable to store the values in the parent. 
Even if you want the child to re render, use hooks in child and uplift their state to the parent and save that as a regular variable than a state varaible. Because you are updating the hook in the parent and every time that happens, the parent will re render.

Comment: Thanks James, I finally opted for another solution

Comment: Hi Sampurna, yes, I just need the first thing you indicated, that it be updated with each change